# Problems involved in going from 0805 to (say) 0402 surface mount?

Tags: pcb

In order to reduce the size of a PCB I will probably have to use smaller SM components. I currently use mostly 0805 passives, and am thinking about going to 0402 or smaller. Apart from power dissipation considerations, any pitfalls I should be aware of when making the transition?

The assembled boards will be made by a specialist contractor

Comment: how good your eyesight is :-)

Comment: Are you assembling the boards yourself? By hand? Oven?

Comment: Just updated the question - the assembled boards will be made by a specialist contractor. My eyesight stops at 0805 and my dexterity at 0603 even with a microscope!

Comment: Don't sneeze! Beware of the voltage limitation of resistors, and also look out for capacitor voltage coefficients. When capacitors are made very compact, even X7R may have very large value drops at full working voltage.

Comment: I think tombstoning can be more of an issue because of unbalanced surface tension, but that's just a feeling based on a handful of instances

Comment: just a note: you can't put a trace between pads on 0402 while you can on 0805, this may make routing more difficult.

Comment: @Cano64 most of the time :). If you're working with 5mil trace/space, you ought to be able to squeeze a trace through if things are _really_ cramped.

Comment: In my experience, 0603 passive components are a good size for the medium-size boards that I have been doing. They are still relatively easy to work with, and they're a good fit in combination with most semiconductor packages. The slight savings when moving from 0603 to 0402 is insignificant relative to the space occupied by traces, vias, etc. and is more than offset by the additional pain of working with 0402. The one place where 0402 has been very useful is as *interstitial* bypass caps on the bottom side of a 1mm-grid BGA. (1mm = 0.04")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0402 obviously is harder to hand assemble. I am young (<30), moderately near sighted (-4.5) and have a reasonable steady hand. I can hand assemble 0402 boards without magnification, but it is very tiresome to do them for hours on end.

If you need to get them assembled by machine; make sure that:

1) Your assembler's pick&place machine can even handle 0402 at a good rate & yield. Some assemblers may charge more because they are forced to run the boards through one of their more modern machines.

2) Double-sided load. Some boards just need this assembly step, like BGA often puts decoupling caps on the bottom of the board. However some assemblers have trouble with 0402 components on the bottom side of the board. They may force you to keep it at 0603 or greater. The risk is that 0402 components will slip of the board in a 2nd reflow cycle.

3) Electrical properties. Obvious one is of course power rating of resistors. Voltage rating is also likely worse, because of the physical smaller dimensions.
But also consider the voltage bias degradation effect of ceramic class 2 capacitors; for smaller packages in same voltage/capacitance this effect may be worse.

On the other hand, some properties like lead inductance is lower. In addition sometimes you can put capacitors right at the chip pins for QFP style packages, while routing signals underneath the chip. In effect the loop area for the decoupling capacitor is much much smaller than a larger size capacitor that may be placed further away to comply with signal routing.